# Constructing a similarity matrix between points

Tags: matrices, matlab, transformation, affine-geometry

I have two images with two sets of corresponding points. In order to align the images I'm trying to compute the similarity matrix that describes the relationship between the corresponding points.

I know it's connected to affine transform:

```
[x y 1] = [u v 1] [a11 a12 0; a21 a22 0; a31 a32 1]
```

Rearranging the equation does `[x y 1] / [u v 1]` give the transform matrix?

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, `a = [x y 1] / [u v 1]` gives the least squares solution to

`a*[u v 1]=[x y 1]`

where `a` is a scalar (not what you want).

To define an affine transformation in a plane, you need at least three points (and their corresponding points after the transformation).

If `[x1 y1]` goes to `[u1 v1]` etc., then what you want is

`A = [[x1 y1 1];[x2 y2 1];[x3 y3 1]] \ [[u1 v1];[u2 v2];[u3 v3]]`.

That will make it so `[x y 1]*A` is the transformed position of `[x y]`.